# C++ boost wave, scoped macro

Tags: c++, boost, scope, macros, wave

Is it possible to have scoped macros using custom defined macros through boost wave?
I know it should a possible with  C++0x however I am working with regular C++.
If it is possible, can you provide link or reference how to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Since I hadn't heard about scoped macros (and apparently they won't be in C++0x), here's some additional information: http://boost-spirit.com/old_docs/wave_v0_9/preliminary_cpp0x_support.html#macro_scoping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that Wave doesn't support macro scoping anymore.  Older documents such as:

- http://boost-spirit.com/old_docs/wave_v0_9/preliminary_cpp0x_support.html#macro_scoping

Discuss support for macro scoping experimentally, but I can't find any mention of it in the newer docs:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/wave/index.html
- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/wave/doc/wave_driver.html

It appears that macro scoping is being left out of C++0x; I'm not sure if it's still being worked by anyone, or if it's been dropped altogether. Looking at the changelog for Boost Wave, it looks like support for scoped macros was removed from Version 1.1.7 in Aug 2004.